# Error al cargar un diccionario a una tabla de tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

estoy intentando [esta](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/tkintertable/wiki/Usage) librería de tkinter que crea tablas tipo excell. El problema es que cuando intento correro el código, la terminal me arroja:

> TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

traté de pasar len() al diccionario pero no funcionó. Si alguien sabe cómo puedo corregor esto, gracias. Aquí el código:

```
ventana=customtkinter.CTk()
ventana.geometry("700x500")

#Base de datos
conn= conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
cursor1=conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
query='SELECT * FROM ticket'
cursor1.execute(query)

#Marco de datos pandas
df_sql_data= pd.DataFrame(cursor1.fetchall())
conn.commit()
conn.close()
print(df_sql_data.to_dict())

tframe = Frame(ventana)
tframe.grid(pady=5, padx=5)
table = TableCanvas(tframe, read_only=True, data=df_sql_data.to_dict())
table.show()


ventana.mainloop()
```

Cuando imprimo el diccionario aparece así, no se si algún valor causa el problema:

> {'Numero': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}, 'Placa': {0: 'aa634sp', 1:
> 'kah86w3', 2: 'hk14r5c', 3: 'aa634sp', 4: 'kah86w'}, 'Conductor': {0:
> 'Mario', 1: 'Miguel', 2: 'Mario', 3: 'Juan', 4: 'Miguel'}, 'Cedula':
> {0: 25814334, 1: 28969334, 2: 25814334, 3: 26725711, 4: 28969334},
> 'Producto': {0: 'maiz', 1: 'aluminio', 2: 'hierro', 3: 'maiz', 4:
> 'hierro'}, 'Numero_guia': {0: 23, 1: 5, 2: 8, 3: 7, 4: 5},
> 'Peso_guia': {0: 5000, 1: 100000, 2: 5000, 3: 50000, 4: 50000},
> 'Proveedor': {0: 'Metalúrgia', 1: 'Metalúrgia', 2: '', 3:
> 'Metalúrgia', 4: 'Metalúrgia'}, 'Cliente': {0: '', 1: '', 2: 'El
> tunal', 3: '', 4: ''}, 'Despacho': {0: '', 1: '', 2: 'Maracay', 3: '',
> 4: ''}, 'Transporte': {0: 'Balarca', 1: 'Balarca', 2: 'Balarca', 3:
> 'Balarca', 4: 'Balarca'}, 'Fecha': {0: '10/25/22', 1: '10/26/22', 2:
> '11/03/22', 3: '11/03/22', 4: '11/03/22'}, 'Hora': {0: '15:02:00 PM',
> 1: '15:59:56 PM', 2: '10:59:32 AM', 3: '11:02:46 AM', 4: '11:06:08
> AM'}, 'Observaciones': {0: 'No', 1: 'No', 2: 'No', 3: 'NO', 4:
> '11:06:08 AM'}, 'Peso_balanza': {0: 4999, 1: 102000, 2: 5001, 3:
> 100000, 4: 100000}, 'Peso_tara': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 46000, 3: 46000, 4:
> 46000}, 'Peso_neto': {0: 4999, 1: 102000, 2: -40999, 3: 54000, 4:
> 54000}, 'Peso_diferencia': {0: -1, 1: 2000, 2: 1, 3: 50000, 4: 50000}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Causa del error

Al parecer, tkintertable espera a que los nombres de columnas en el diccionario sean cadenas. Entonces, tkintertable asume que esto es cierto, a pesar de que en realidad son numeros. Y luego, para mostrar la tabla, intenta obtener el largo de estas "cadenas" y, como son números, Python se queja.

#### Otro error

Cuando hacés pandas.to_dict, por default, el formato del diccionario es:

```
{column -> {index -> value}}
```

Pero tkintertable espera el siguiente formato:

```
{index -> {column -> value}}
```

Si no hubieras tenido el problema con el que viniste, te hubieras encontrado con un desastre de tabla.

#### Solución

Se me ocurre un par de modificaciones a tu código. Primero, el hacer que el dataframe, que crea por default columnas numeradas desde el 0, tenga esta misma numeración pero usando cadenas, no enteros.
Esto lo podemos lograr con una comprensión de listas que convierta cada columna a cadena. Esta nueva lista serán las nuevas columnas del Dataframe.
Y la mejor parte es que no requerirás darle nombres y cantidad fija de columnas a tu Dataframe!!!

```
df_sql_data.columns = [str(col) for col in df_sql_data.columns]
```

Luego, como dije antes, te ocurrirá otro error. Vamos a solucionarlo diciendole a pandas explicitamente como debe generar el diccionario. Para eso, usaremos la cadena "index".

```
table = TableCanvas(tframe, read_only=True, data=df_sql_data.to_dict("index"))
```

#### Mi código de prueba completo

```
import customtkinter
from tkintertable import TableCanvas
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd

ventana=customtkinter.CTk()
ventana.geometry("700x500")

#Base de datos

#Marco de datos pandas
df_sql_data= pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
df_sql_data.columns = [str(col) for col in df_sql_data.columns]

tframe = Frame(ventana)
tframe.grid(pady=5, padx=5)
table = TableCanvas(tframe, read_only=True, data=df_sql_data.to_dict("index"))
table.show()

ventana.mainloop()
```

#### Referencias

- [tkintertable: Get data into the table](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/tkintertable/wiki/Usage#get-data-into-the-table)
- [pandas.DataFrame.to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

Comment: Listo @DanteS. lo probé y funcionó, muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada! Me alegro c: